# What are these curious cetaceans?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, mammals, species, aquatic-biology

At the beginning of the superb documentary film “Un jardin d’Eden sous les mers” (“A garden of Eden under the seas”) [1], we see a group of curious cetaceans. At about 1 min.

**What are these cetaceans?**

I think that they are odontocetes. But what species are they? This is a mystery.

[1] [Documentary film “Un jardin d’Eden sous les mers” (“A garden of Eden under the seas”)](http://www.arte.tv/guide/fr/044067-000-A/un-jardin-d-eden-sous-les-mers). It will be rebroadcasted on [Arte](http://www.arte.tv) on 2016‑04‑01 at 7:45 Paris time. [You can watch it on-line here](http://www.replay-documentaire.com/jardin-deden-mers-streaming/).

Thank you.

Comment: Adding a screenshot would enhance the change of getting an answer, not many people will go and watch a movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am completely shooting in the dark here, but do you mean the ones between 1:06 - 1:13 minutes in the video? (After Hammerhead and before Baby and Mama white Shark :) )

[image]

**SPECIES IDENTIFIED:** *Pseudorca crassidens* (False Killer Whale)

[image]
[image]

**Matching image from the internet (used for identification):**

[image]

Courtsey: [UAE Dolphin Project](http://wp.uaedolphinproject.org/?page_id=1006)

PS: Images are screenshot from the video [Documentary film “Un Jardin d’Eden sous les mers” (“A garden of Eden under the seas”)](http://www.replay-documentaire.com/jardin-deden-mers-streaming/) are completly owned by the owner of the video and "arte HD" channel.

PPS: Anyone reading this, if you haven't already, then please watch the video. Though it is completely in french, the videography is amazing.

References:

1. [Pacific Islands Cetaceans](http://www.cms.int/pacific-cetaceans/en/species/pseudorca-crassidens)
2. [Other Whales](http://wildwhales.org/other-species/)

Comment: Yes, I mean these nice cetaceans. I have thought about pseudorcas too, in the meantime. Indeed, these cetaceans are pseudorcas! Thank you for this great answer!